# Delimiting a CSV file created by Python Script

Tags: python, csv

I am pulling data from a Rally server, and would like to write it to a CSV file and create snapshots.
I am creating the file with:

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
timestr = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
f = open(timestr+'FileName.csv', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

#all of the setup and functions

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

The output I am writing to file comes from:

```
for item in response:
    print("%s, %s, %s, %s" % (item.Attribute1, item.Attribute2, item.Attribute3, item.Attribute4))
```

The problem is that the strings will occasionally have a comma in it already. This is true for every usual character. I do not wish to replace the commas in said strings.

Is there a special character I can use that an Excel CSV file would recognize and be able to split into columns properly, or can I somehow tell the file to delimit using a multiple characters such as ",,"

Comment: Have you looked at the `csv` module?

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now; I'm new to python (I mainly work with SQL or tools like Tableau). My initial search for an answer didn't turn up the csv module, but I could have guessed that one existed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: One hint if you're new to python: Don't redirect sys.stdout to a file just to use print. Instead use an approach like `with open('file.csv', 'w') as out: out.write('text')`

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in csv modules that can handle various formats (such as excel)
 and can handle special options (such as escaping) automatically for you.

The [Writer object from the CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) sounds like what you're looking for.